# All steps to set up and resolve subdomain.localhost to 127.0.0.1?

Tags: macos, unix, dns, localhost, subdomain

I suddenly feel stubborn about my subdomain on localhost not working. My `/etc/hosts` file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost

127.0.0.1   develop2win.de
127.0.0.1   develop2win.de

127.0.0.1   alomvar.localhost
```

Putting all host names for one IP in one line like this does not work either:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost alomvar.localhost develop2win.de www.develop2win.de
```

I also restarted the DNS resolver appropriate for OS X 10.9 Mavericks with the following command:

```
dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

But issuing `nslookup alomvar.localhost` on terminal yields the following:

```
Server:     192.168.178.1
Address:    192.168.178.1#53

** server can't find alomvar.localhost: NXDOMAIN
```

That is the IP of the router in my local network. It appears like the localhost hosts file is skipped for resolution in this case. Before the process `develop2win.de` was successfully resolved and pointed to a local Apache virtual host. But now not even that works anymore, same error as above (WTF?). However, looking up plain `localhost` works fine, still:

```
Server:     192.168.178.1
Address:    192.168.178.1#53

Name:   localhost
Address: 127.0.0.1
```

**Update 1**: I did a reboot, too, without any change. It seems like DNS queries are not resolved locally at all but sent to my router instead.

What am I missing? Did somebody else try to set up a subdomain for localhost on OS X Mavericks? This is not even about Apache, just the DNS thing.

Here is a [screenshot of my DNS configuration in system preferences](http://shared.alomvar.com/355b278598384a9f8818ec5dea0223b9.png), by the way. Since I do not have enough reputation yet to embed images, this is a link to external site.

**Update 2**: I performed checks with `host` and `ping` commands in terminal, as dave_thompson_085 pointed out. For localhost it works fine:

```
$ host localhost
localhost has address 127.0.0.1
```

But for the subdomain not:

```
$ host alomvar.localhost
Host alomvar.localhost not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Pinging localhost works fine, too:

```
$ ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.078 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.085 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.076 ms
^C
--- localhost ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.048/0.072/0.085/0.014 ms
```

And now, irritatingly, so it works as well for the subdomain:

```
$ ping alomvar.localhost
PING alomvar.localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.039 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.075 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.091 ms
^C
--- alomvar.localhost ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.039/0.062/0.091/0.022 ms
```

How can I ping without problems but not resolve the subdomain? Apparently it should work like this, when I look on how other people did it around the internet. I am not a crack regarding networking. I probably broke something else than what is directly needed to set this up.

I also executed `dig`on localhost and the subdomain. The output is rather long and I think this question is cluttered enough already. See [this file](http://shared.alomvar.com/0fa2720a9a774d83b34818662edcd570.txt) for dig output.

**Update 3**: When disconnecting my Mac from the network (disabling ethernet network adapter) `dig`and `host` fail looking up localhost, too.

**Update 4**: I found out that works within browsers to show the Apache virtual host listening to the so named host. It is not a solution to the problem, but a circumstance I can live and work with. However, I am still interested in resolving the issue. If anybody got any further idea, tell me.

Comment: `nslookup` (and also `dig`) ONLY talks to DNS servers, it does not use the full DNS-resolver logic like other (real?) programs. Try `host` to just resolve, or `ping` to resolve and do only a few harmless packets. While this is true for most if not all Unix, MacOSX emphasises it in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nslookup.1.html at "Mac OS X Notice".

Comment: Thank you for the hints @dave_thompson_085, I updated my question with the results of `host`, `dig` and `ping`.

Comment: Sorry, I was half wrong: I remembered `host` as doing normal resolution, but rechecking the man page I see it also does ONLY DNS server(s). Thus `nslookup dig host` all ignoring the data in your hosts file is as documented, unfortunately. So go with `ping`.

Comment: I have the same problem `127.0.0.1 subdomain.localhost` inside `/etc/hosts/`. **subdomain.localhost** pings well, however if I open the browser at `http://subdomain.localhost`, I get a `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

`dig`, `host`, and `nslookup` all bypass the system name resolver, and query DNS directly. Thus, they won't see names defined in /etc/hosts (unless they're *also* defined in the DNS service), or any mDNS (aka Bonjour) .local names, or Computer entries in directory services, or...

If you want to see what the system resolver sees, the best tool is `dscacheutil`. Unfortunately, its syntax is rather clumsy (`dscacheutil -q host -a name alomvar.localhost`), so it's generally quicker to use something like `ping` that uses the system name resolver. But if you want full details (e.g. whether a name resolves to multiple addresses), `dscacheutil` is the way to go.

Comment: Is it still applicable for OS X Mavericks? I checked out the man pages. Performing the query like in your answer returns any output. `dscacheutil -statistics` states "Unable to get details from the cache node" (same with `-cachedump`). I am just asking, since as far as I know there were some changes with Mavericks in that matter.

Comment: @Alomvar yes, this is still true in Mavericks. Apple has changed how name resolution works quite a bit over the history of OS X, but the DNS tools (`dig`, `host`, and `nslookup`) always bypassed the system policy, and `dscacheutil` has (since its appearance) followed the system policy. Several of `dscacheutil`'s other functions have broken (e.g. `dscacheutil -flushcache` now requires `sudo`, and doesn't seem to entirely work even then...), but it still does lookups ok. Oh, one thing did change in Mavericks: Network Utility.app's Lookup tab now uses the system policy (it used to use `dig`).