# How does linux resolve wildcard locahost subdomains (e.g. : `ping test.localhost`) when `test.localhost` does not exist in /etc/hosts or dns server?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, localhost, hosts-file

For example in ubuntu 20.04 LTS where the `/etc/hosts` file is empty:

```
>>> cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

`ping` still works for any subdomain of localhost:

```
>>> ping test.localhost
PING test.localhost(ip6-localhost (::1)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.058 ms
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
^C
--- test.localhost ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1028ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.049/0.053/0.058/0.004 ms
```

or:

```
>>> ping test2.localhost
PING test2.localhost(ip6-localhost (::1)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
64 bytes from ip6-localhost (::1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
^C
--- test2.localhost ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.042/0.052/0.063/0.010 ms
```

This [answer alludes that the system resolver is involved](https://superuser.com/a/781633/537036) but how does it actually happen?

If `localhost` in `/etc/hosts` is replaced with another value the subdomains no longer work:

```
>>> cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       testname


>>> ping testname
PING testname (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from testname (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.071 ms
64 bytes from testname (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.080 ms
^C
--- testname ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1011ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.071/0.075/0.080/0.004 ms

>>> ping new.testname
ping: new.testname: Name or service not known
```

Why does it work for localhost and no other hostname and how is it achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name resolution on Linux (Glibc) uses the "name service switch" system, where each data source has a separate module responsible for it. For example, the `libnss_files` module is responsible for reading /etc/hosts (and /etc/passwd, /etc/group) while the `libnss_dns` module makes DNS queries. There are similarly modules for reading data from LDAP, NIS, and even SQL.

Resolving 'localhost' as well as the system hostname is handled by the `libnss_myhostname` module (which now comes as part of systemd). You can see it listed in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. The systemd-bundled version also handles subdomains of 'localhost' and the special name '_gateway'.

The *systemd-resolved* program has its own `libnss_resolve` nsswitch module as well, talks directly to the daemon (without using loopback DNS), and it also duplicates most of the same special-name handling that libnss_myhostname has.